# Database transactions(node-jdbc) in NodeJS meets async requests-que

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jdbc, architecture

**First some general information**

I'm using Typescript with NodeJS v18.16
My node-project includes express.js, node-jdbc, and pm2

---

**Introduction**

Hello community,

I am currently creating a backend in NodeJS that will serve an HTTP-Based API for altering / reading different Databases.

Let's say you have several functions `foo()` and `bar()` which add / update rows on a Database-Table. They can be called individually or by other functions or in combination.

`foo()` changes different Tables than `bar()`.

`foo()` and `bar()` depend on `DbAccess` class which provides (async) CRUD (**C**reate, **R**ead, **U**pdate, **D**elete) methods as well as `startTransaction()` and `commit()`.

`startTransaction()` Marks the begining of a transaction and `commit()` should make the made changes on the DB persistent.

---

**The Problem**

First of all: Connections to the DB are limited. Older solutions showed that there will be more requests to serve then my maxpoolsize.

Now I get two different requests. One request will call `foo()` without problems but makes `bar()` throw an error. This would lead to a rollback on the whole transaction (including all changed data since i invoked `startTransaction()`) but due to the asynchronous nature of the CRUD methods the second request already started to make changes via `foo()` and I don't want them to rollback.

The solution would be to "lock" the used database connection as soon as i invoke `startTransaction()`. But how do i separate calls i want to put on hold from those which i actually want to be executed.

---

**Solutions**

I could pass the DB-connection-reference-object to each sub-function like this:

```
  foo(con?: ManagedConnection) {
    // create new DB-Con if not given
    con = (!con) ? new ManagedConnection() : con
    // do awesome stuff with con
  }
```

But this would be a real bummer since I also need to get connection details everywhere... This is just wrong.

I also could just serve one Request at a time and put everything on a queue. This would probably decrease the performance a lot.

I really hope someone can help me. Cheers!

P.S. Gonna edit the Question several times probably to improve, clarify the problem or fix grammar